Como conectar app desktop C# a un Servidor SOCKET.IO con NodeJS
Buenas tardes primero que nada tengan un cordial saludo, vengo a uds para intentar encontrar una solución ante mi problema.
Cree el siguiente servidor con Socket.IO y NodeJs


    const http = require("http");
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    
    const {Server} = require("socket.io");
    const io = new Server(server);
    let all_nsp = [ ];
    
    io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
        console.log("Un usuario se ha conectado. ID: " + socket.handshake.auth.username);
    
        socket.on("disconnect", ( ) => {
            console.log("Un usuario se ha desconectado");
        })
    
        socket.on("chat", ( msg ) => {
            io.emit("chat", msg)
        })
    
        socket.on("createNew", ( nsp ) => {
            if( all_nsp.indexOf( nsp ) === -1 ) {
                console.log(`Creando el Espacio de Nombre: ${ nsp }`);
    
                let custom = io.of(`/${nsp}`);
                custom.on('connection', (sck)=>{
                    console.log(`Usuario: ${ sck.handshake.auth.username }, Conectado en sala: ${ sck.handshake.auth.nameroom }`);
    
                    sck.on("hi", ( msg ) => {
                        custom.emit('hi', msg);
                    });
                });
    
                all_nsp.push( nsp );
            }
            else
                console.log(`Espacio de Nombre: ${ nsp }, ya se encuentra registrado`);
        })
        
    });
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/cliente/index.html`)
    })
    
    server.listen(5000, ()=> {
        console.log("Servidor Corriendo en puerto http://localhost:5000")
    } );


pero el problema esta cuando intento conectar una aplicación que estoy haciendo con C# windowform (como decir el chat que se puede manejar desde la web tambien quiero que se pueda manejar desde una app desktop) pero no logro conectar, he conseguido varios códigos pero ninguno me funciona


    using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;
    using System;
    
    namespace chat
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:5000");
                socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
                {
                    socket.Emit("chat", "hola desde c#");
                });
                socket.On("chat", (data) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    socket.Disconnect();
                });
                Console.ReadLine();
    
            }
        }
    }

Alguien puede ayudarme por favor

Tu código c# va crear el socket y salir inmediatamente, y no esperar para una conexión.  Miráte los ejemplos aquí.  (Y Quobject está en desuso.)

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

amigo @piterM no se si me di a explicar bien, tengo un servidor hecho en nodejs, y necesito crear un cliente en c# que se conecte a ese servidor pero por mas que hago y hago nada logro conseguir como conectar ambas aplicaciones, ni siquiera con una app de terceros como cliente, sera que puedes ayudarme por favor
